# ANDROID. Send request to database from two RecyclerViews and receive data in third RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

There is a `fragment` which contains three `RecyclerViews` (all of three contain `CardViews`). One recycler displays city names and second displays fuel types. The third recycler is supposed to display filling stations and corresponding prices for selected city and fuel type.

All data is stored in *MySQL* database on web-server and query is written in a *PHP* file. I have adapters for all 3 recyclers, and the question is how to display data in the third recycler when user clicks on the first or the second recycler, all of that **in one fragment**. Data is sent to query from first and second recycler, while the result should be displayed in third.

*If needed, I will post my code (fragment, adapter or anything else you need).*

I am relatively new in 'Android programming' and I would really appreciate some help with this case.
I have already searched for the solution, but there was no complete or correct solution for it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the data from the fragment to an activity you can pass it with intent.putExtra.

from a **fragment** to an **activity**, in the adapter you will do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (context, NameOfActivity.class);
intent.putExtra ("nameFromArgument", value);
context.startActivity (intent);
```

in the activity that will receive the fragment data you will do, within onCreate:

```
Extra bundle = getIntent (). GetExtras ();
String received = extra.getString ("nameFromArgument");
```

after that you will get the data from the received string that came from the adapter and will pass it in your request, if you want to pass more than one parameter to the activity, just repeat **intent.putExtra** always changing the **nameFromArgument** and receiving the same way in the activity, you too you can pass an object if you want

Comment: Actually, I am sending data from a fragment (from two recyclers inside it) and receiving data back from database into third recycler located in the **same** fragment.

Comment: As I understand it is simple, each cardview has a position, you will get that position, link a click event to the selected card position with what you want to do, in case you send it to your api, the response of your api you will notify on the third card, recreating it when the response is received